# SQL UNIQUE key not treating international characters as distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding, unique

I have just exported a MySQL database (in LATIN1) and converted to UTF-8 in the process, and imported on to a newer system.

It seemed to go OK, but I did hit a few instances where a UNIQUE key threw an error because two entries which differed only in an international character, e.g.

"åle" was not considered unique from "ale"

I did not find anything in the documentation on UNIQUE keys that mentioned character sets or encodings at all.

How can I configure the database to ensure that it considers these letters unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the "COLLATION" setting for the column in question. You can see the current collation with "SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN yourtablename".

For example, "utf8_general_ci" considers "ale", "åle" and "ALE" the same. Depending on your use case, something like "utf8_swedish_ci" or "utf8_bin" might be more appropriate.  Note that changing collation will also change what ".. where yourcolumn=value" matches, and the ordering of "...order by yourcolumn".

You can change the collation with "ALTER TABLE" (for a single column), or database-wide. More information in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/globalization.html